# ASP.net WebApi pushing notifications to an iOS/Android mobile game written in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, asp.net-web-api, push-notification

I'd like to use Unity3D to write a game to run on multiple mobile devices (Android / iOS / Windows phone); the game will send a HTTP Request to a .NET ASP MVC WebApi telling it that it is interested in a specific piece of data, and whenever that data is modified on the web server I'd like to send a push notification to the Unity3D game.

I can foresee I will need two types of notifications. The first would simply update some game state, and the 2nd would also need the phone to alert the user of the notification in the case where they have switched the game off and put their phone away.

Can someone recommend any libraries for Unity3D, and some articles for how to implement the server side please?

Answer (score 0):

> the game will send a HTTP Request to a .NET ASP MVC WebApi telling it
>   that it is interested in a specific piece of data, and whenever that
>   data is modified on the web server I'd like to send a push
>   notification to the Unity3D game

Implement this by yourself.

**1**.Make a request to the server with [`UnityWebRequest`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest.html).

**2**.On the server, accept the request then create a unique Key and store both unique Key and information about the request on a database.

**4**.Return that unique Key to the client.

**5**.On the server disconnect client and start processing the request.

**6**.On the client, connect to the server every 3 or 5 seconds when waiting for data from server. Each time you connect, make the connection with the unique key that was sent by the server. You can do this with POST/GET query.

**7**.When client connects with a unique key, take that key and check if processing is done or if new data is available. If this is true then send the result back to the client. Remove the unique key from the database. If the data is not yet ready, send a status code to the client to let the client know that the data is not yet ready, then disconnect client.

- Client = Requests from your Unity3D app.
- Server = Your server.

Comment: Hi. I'm interested specifically in push notifications so that I don't have to poll.